# Using webpack to bundle CSS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, webpack

I have a few NPM mudules I'm trying to bundle with webpack so I don't have to use CDN.

I was able to figure out how to get the `.js` files working but I don't understand how to get the `.css` files for the same modules.

For example I have `Bootstrap` has a NPM module. In my entry.js file I have `require('bootstrap');` but that only gives me the javascript files.

I've seen other npm modules like `bootstrap-webpack` etc but I don't understand why I need to download another module if I already have bootstrap part of my `node_modules`. Same with things like 'font-awesome', 'animate.css', 'select2'

What am I missing?

Comment: Please check [webpack loader](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html) like a [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader)

Comment: Ive seen it but I don't really see how to use it with NPM modules. If my `entry.js` already has `require('bootstrap')` do I need to write another one but `bootstrap.css`

Comment: Cause the comment was prolonged, I added a answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know the Bootstrap supports the commonJS module loader. So you can load the bootstrap js files using require().

When you use require('bootstrap'), a bootstrap's entry file is loaded then the entry file load some another file part of library. (Actually the bootstrap entry file only load one file `/dist/js/bootstrap.js`) [check official] repo(https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/js)).

In this process, if the bootstrap use `require('some.css')` to load css, webpack try load css. But require('some.css') is not generalised method. Without webpack or browserify or other build system, css can not loaded by require(). that's why you must need `bootstrap-webpack`.

Additionally, the bootstrap can used not only in webpack but also common environment like a in requirejs(AMD) or by `<script>` tag. So you have to load css manually or by means of `bootstrap-webpack`.